# LWC - Get RecordId from @api property

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am wanting to get the Record Id when a user selects a record. I store this in a @api propery. I would like this Id so I can use the wire service *getRecord* to retrieve some fields and then I can pre popluate them on the ui.

HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={displayParentOpp}> <!-- only show if user meets pre conditions --> 
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Opportunity">
            <lightning-input-field id="parentOpp" required variant="Neutral" field-name="Parent_OpportunityId__c"
                value={parentOppSelected} onchange={handleParentOppSelectedChange}>
            </lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS:

```
@api parentOppSelected;
parentOppId;

handleParentOppSelectedChange(event) {
    //how to get Parent Opp Id?
    this.parentOppSelected = event.detail.value;
}


@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$parentOppId', fields: fields })
account({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
    } else if (error) {
    }
}
```

Below is the console log when the parent opp is selected. I am unsure how to retrieve the record Id from here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`@api` means a property is read-only within your own component (violate this rule at your own risk). That said, you can assign the value to `this.parentOppId` directly, and the wire handler will take care of the rest for you.